# Java program for Money change

Tags: java

I want a java program for money change,

**Example:** If I enter Rs.98 then i need the result like below,

```
1(Rs. 50) - Rs. 50
2(Rs. 20) - Rs. 40
1(Rs. 5) - Rs. 5
1(Rs. 2) - Rs. 2
1(Rs.1) - Rs. 1
```

I have tried the logic with switch cases and many if and else, but I could not achieve what I want. Please give some idea/logic to initiate this..

The program which i tried is,

```
package in.javadomain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class PowerOfTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = 98;
        int[] money = { 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000 };
        ArrayList<Integer> moneyChange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i<money.length; i++) {
            if (input > money[i]) {
                //input = money[i];
                moneyChange.add(money[i]);
                //System.out.println(input);
            }
        }
        ListIterator li = moneyChange.listIterator(moneyChange.size());
        int changes = 0;
        while(li.hasPrevious()){
            int temp = (int) li.previous();
            if(temp<input){
                // System.out.println(temp);
                changes = changes+temp;
                System.out.println(changes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is,

```
50
70
80
85
87
88
```

But I want the order like below,

```
50
70
90
95
97
98
```

Please try to help me out to achieve...

Comment: Post your code showing what have you tried and what's the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2):

Start to divide with the biggest coin and and then continue with the rest.

98 / 50 = 1 -> rest 48

48 / 20 = 2 -> rest 8

8 / 5 = 1 -> rest 3

3 / 2 = 1 -> rest 1

1 / 1  = 1

finished

Comment: It's just a hint for you because you said you doesn't know where to start

Comment: @Naveen You did not specify 120 or 565... you specified 98... you dont even deserve help man.

Comment: You can do it also with 565 the way I explained

Comment: @Naveen after your comments, nobody would like to give a solution since you're showing lack of respect for other professionals and even posting incomplete questions and showing no effort to solve it.

Comment: @Naveen you still seem like a "self-entitled" ungrateful "asker". Good luck buddy.

Comment: @Luiggi Everyone here coming to get solution for our problem only, not to play with other professionals. I mentioned give me some idea/logic to initiate i did not expect whole program...

Comment: @Naveen ok then. Use a dynamic programming algorithm that will calculate the change for a specific amount of money based on the currency determination stored in an array. The algorithm will start retrieving the results when the amount is 1, 2, 3... to `<amount>` but since it is on dynamic programming it should use the solution of the latest problem to get the solution of the current one.